# user-interactive refresh of dynamic menu

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, pdo

I will try to make this short. I am (as many) very new at php/jquery and 100% self-taught. I am trying to build a webpage so that we can use it
at work (non-profit research) to follow subjects during their stay.

I am creating a dynamic ul using the usual li which points to the results returned by a PDO result query.

QUESTION 1: Is there a way to have the user select/click on a particular li and have the page reload and rerun the query using the users input? Then use the same page to 
display the results of the new query?

I am trying to build a simple webpage that allows the user to navigate through a MySQL database and easily insert/input the time and description at the right location within the SQL database.

Question 2:  I am using PDO for security reasons... was advised to me by a friend who does a bit of this. Do I need to close the connection after the query?

Even pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated... I have been at this for days!

Thanks all!

RC

Thank you for your reply Evan... Sadly, I am a newbie with mostly science knowledge!!

I heard about AJAX in the past. When I added your code it only printed the text to the screen. Could you guide me a bit more to learn about it... any good sites? will try youtube now. below is my code... maybe that will help. Anyways, thank you for your help so far!

```
<div data-role="content">

<div data-role="controlgroup">

<ul>

<?php

global $db;

$st = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM category");
$st->execute();
foreach ($st as $stmenuselection) {
echo '<li><a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">'.$stmenuselection['name'].'</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: better way is to consider each request as a transaction: so close the connection after each query (that means after each request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1:

I think what you really want to do here is use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to ping the service you have created in PHP to get the updated information.  So you would have something like:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    // get the li that was clicked
    var $this = $(this);

    // get some kind of info from the li
    var data = $this.data('info');

    // use ajax to query your php service
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: { info : data }
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
      // update your page here using jQuery
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
});
```

2) Close connection after each query

In terms of having a website to navigate a sql db... isn't the point of the website to just extract the information you would like to display in a way that makes sense to your users, then use ajax to query your PHP service which will handle all the changes to the db?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Evan... Sadly, I am a newbie with mostly science knowledge!!

I heard about AJAX in the past. When I added your code it only printed the text to the screen. Could you guide me a bit more to learn about it... any good sites? will try youtube now. below is my code... maybe that will help. Anyways, thank you for your help so far!